# java new line regular expression

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, newline

Hi I'm working on capturing correct group for regular expression in Java. (My version is 1.8.0_91)

This is the given document:

**

```
<ABC>Hi Hello</ABC> bla bla bla <ABC>Hi
Hello</ABC>
```

**

My pattern to compile is

```
String pattern = "<ABC>((.|\\n)+?)</ABC>";
```

I want to capture both first 'Hi Hello' which is in the same line, and second 'Hi Hello' written in two different lines due to enter(\n). But it won't work. This only captures the first 'Hi Hello'. How should I change the regular expression above?

Comment: Just to make clear - you want to have 2 different matches using this pattern? First `<ABC>...</ABC>` and then second `<ABC>...</ABC>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default . matches every character except new line character.

In this case, you will need DOTALL option, which will make . matches any character, including new line character. DOTALL option can be specified inline as (?s). For example:

`(?s)<ABC>((.|\\n)+?)</ABC>`

Comment: But this is why he wrote in his pattern `(.|\\n)`, means `.` OR `newline`.